# Best Way to minimize the repeats of results

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing an quiz game for android with sqlite and i want make a question: What's the best way to try minimize the repeats of a question? I try to randomize the results of a query and select one but this is not the best way.

Regards for help

Comment: order your questions all in one select by RAND() or a similar ordering - then loop until the quiz is over.

Comment: @Randy: Does RAND guarantee that each record is only selected once?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the questions and store it in a List . Then shuffle the collection using [Collections.shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) method. Now remove one question at a time. This ensure the unique random question every time

Comment: yes this is true, but and in more than 1 instance of game
? is good idea mantain the frequency of a question?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how large your set is why not just keep track of what is called between instances of the game with an added column in the database?

As questions are called, keep track of their id number with something simple - like an array list. Use this to avoid calling the same question twice. Then at the end of the game or, to track over multiple sessions onPause or onStop, update a column in the database to reflect whether a question was called before.

You could use this to either (1) ensure the same qustions are not called over multiple sessions with somthing like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE KEY_WAS_USED = 0
```

or if you want to get creative - as you hint at in your comment you could track how many times each question was called and then balance the frequency of repeats.

Comment: but if i use the method of frequency probably the questions will be choosed forever with the same order...Ex: if i have 3 questions in the first time playing will be a random choose: if i choose 1 in the next round i can choose 2 or 3, if i choose 2 in the next time i will choose with certain 3..and apart from this step i always choose 1, 2 ,3 ...Any solution for this?

Comment: If you do it the way you describe - yes. But I wouldn't necessarily use a strict selection model. If you use an average or weighted average model - i.e. questions selected less times appear more - you can balance frequency so you call less of the same questions over and over again. But you're right in your example that with a small question base, elminating those already selected leaves you with limited options.